# Is it possible to ask Allah swt to forgive All of my past, present, and future Sins?

Tags: tawba

Allah is the most merciful and his mercy is infinite, so I really hope that Allah is able to accept this request of mine.

Comment: Well yes of course. I think the question you meant to ask was if Allah would grant such a prayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely you can ask for that, you can ask for anything you like as long as it's not something sinful.

Prophet Mohammed use to make a similar du'a =

> **اللَّهُمَّ اغْفِرْ لِي ذَنْبِي كُلَّهُ دِقَّهُ وَجِلَّهُ وَأَوَّلَهُ وَآخِرَهُ وَعَلاَنِيَتَهُ وَسِرَّهُ**
>
> **Allahummaghfir li dhanbi kullahu, diqqahu wa jillahu, wa `awwalahu wa akhirahu, wa alaniyatahu wa sirrah**
>
> **O Allah, forgive me all my sins, small and great, earliest and what is towards the end, open and secret.**

This hadith found in [Sahih Muslim]

Now the question is, what will we do to earn his forgiveness?  Obedience to Allah is the best way,

Comment: The missed the subtlety of the poorly phrase question. It's asking for future sins as well. The answer to which I think is no.

Comment: @user5336 alaikum salam, pls ask forgiveness for me also.

Answer (score 0):

you may ask for that, you can ask for anything you like as long as it's not something sinful,not good or najaiz-o-haram.

But you also must have to decide that in future i wouldn't repeat the sin from your heart. For Allah Azwajal every thing is possible. Allah Azwajal says, ask me i will give you, ask for my mercy i will forgive you'r sin , but we have to made a promise to Allah Azwajal that we we'll never do that sin again.

Answer (score 0):

Salaam,
Brother, Allah SWT is the most merciful, most gracious and all knowing and whoever heartily prays to him he grants his wish.